# How do I exclude certain values from an average in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, average

If I have this table: `Item(ItemID, descr, onhand, price)`

I am looking for prices that fall below the average of all the others. So let's say I have `item 1`, then I would be comparing it to the average of items `2-5` rather than the average of items `1-5`. I know it will be a correlated subquery, but I can't figure out this bit about the average. So how do I exclude a non-specific item from the average?

Comment: Could you please explain your requirement with an example. It would be good if you provide the create and insert statements, and show your desired output.

Comment: why do you want to exclude each item from the average?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: as proved by @1010's transforms we can just compare items price to total average.

### Smart solution:

(*provides same results as straightforward, but executes much faster on large data*)

```
SELECT 
    t.ItemId,
    t.descr,
    t.onhand,
    t.price
from Item t
JOIN (
SELECT AVG(price) AS price
FROM Item 
) item_avg ON t.price < item_avg.price
```

### Straightforward solution:

This does the trick, however, at the moment I can't see ways to optimize it (it's an "execution plan killer")

```
SELECT 
    t.ItemId,
    t.descr,
    t.onhand,
    t.price
from Item t
WHERE t.price < (
  SELECT AVG(T2.price) 
  FROM Item t2 
  WHERE t2.ItemId <> t.ItemID
)
```

For a table with such values:

```
ItemId  descr   onhand  price   CalculatedAverage
1       desc1   1       23      40
2       desc2   1       5       44.5
3       desc3   1       100     20.75
4       desc4   1       35      37
5       desc5   1       20      40.75
```

It produces the following output

```
ItemId  descr   onhand  price
1       desc1   1       23
2       desc2   1       5
4       desc4   1       35
5       desc5   1       20
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say item i has price p_i, then you want to check

```
p_i < (p_1 + ... + p_i-1 + p_i+1 + ... + p_n)/(n-1)
```

but it's equivalent to

```
      p_i * (n-1) < (p_1 + ... + p_n) - p_i

p_i * (n-1) + p_i < (p_1 + ... + p_n)

  p_i * (n-1 + 1) < (p_1 + ... + p_n)

    (p_i * n) / n < (p_1 + ... + p_n) / n

              p_i < AVG(p)
```

so just compare each price with the average of all prices. it's the same.

EDIT

following [Kirill's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838239/how-do-i-exclude-certain-values-from-an-average-in-sql-oracle/29849678?noredirect=1#comment47847399_29849678) suggestion here's another query to get the prices below the average

```
SELECT ItemID, descr, onhand, price
  FROM Item
 WHERE price < (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Item)
```

Comment: `p_i-1 + p_i+1` instead of `p_n-1 + p_n+1`

Comment: I think it would logical to include in your answer the SQL that implements this (see my answer's edit)